# why the command 'exec' can remove the blocking state of fifo file?

Tags: multithreading, shell, exec, mkfifo

I'am studying how to use multi thread to process tasks.And i noticed that the fifo file can help that.here is the effect:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_cmd(){
echo "process $1"
sleep 3
}
ff="d:/myfifo/$$.fifo"
mkfifo $ff
exec 7<>$ff
for i in {1..10};do echo;done >&7
for i in {1..1000};do {
read -u 7
my_cmd $i
echo >&7
}& done
rm $ff
wait
echo "end"
```

This shell script can run normally(process 1000 cmds, 10 at a time).And i modified this script slightly

```
#!/bin/bash
my_cmd(){
echo "process $1"
sleep 3
}
ff="d:/myfifo/$$.fifo"
mkfifo $ff
exec 7<>$ff
for i in {1..10};do echo;done >$ff     # modified
for i in {1..1000};do {
read <$ff                              # modified
my_cmd $i
echo >$ff                              # modified
}& done
wait
rm $ff
echo "end"
```

As expected,the second script can also run normally.But i made a error when i modified it again.

```
#!/bin/bash
my_cmd(){
echo "process $1"
sleep 3
}
ff="d:/myfifo/$$.fifo"
mkfifo $ff
# exec 7<>$ff                                 modified
for i in {1..10};do echo;done >$ff    
for i in {1..1000};do {
read <$ff                              
my_cmd $i
echo >$ff                              
}& done
wait
rm $ff
echo "end"
```

The script wait a input to fifo file,because the fifo file entered a blocking state.It seems that this command 'exec 7<>$ff' lifted the blocking state of this fifo file.So is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, at least (Not sure about other OSes, and POSIX doesn't define a behavior), opening a fifo for both reading and writing will succeed at once without blocking waiting for the other end of the pipe to be opened.

So when you commented out the `exec 7<>$ff` line, the next line `for i in {1..10};do echo;done >$ff` will opening the fifo for writing, and block waiting for something else to open it for writing before going on. With the original version using the `exec`, it was already opened for reading so there was no need to block.

The [Linux `fifo(7)` documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) does note

> A process that uses both  ends  of  the  connection  in order to communicate with itself should be very careful to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: so this command just only opens the fifo file on the writting and reading ends?

Comment: @dotzhang As file descriptor 7 so it can be used later like in the first one, yeah.